# Physical intuition for negative pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, pressure, cosmological-inflation, cosmological-constant

Ordinarily, we think of pressure, such as the pressure of a gas as an outward push exerted on the walls of the gas container. In nonequilibrium, the pressure tries to make the volume expand. But the term negative pressure cannot be an inward pull of some kind that would cause contraction of volume. Because cosmological constant (which has negative pressure) causes accelerated expansion of the Universe instead of contraction. So negative pressure cannot be thought of as inward pull aiding contraction. Then what is the intuition for negative pressure? Please explain your answer supported by some math/thermodynamics.

Comment: Are you talking about absolute pressure or gauge pressure?

Comment: I don't know what is gauge pressure. I'm talking about normal pressure due to a field or a fluid.

Comment: By negative pressure, you mean a partial vacuum, right?

Answer (score 1):

OP's intuition about negative pressure as an “inward pull of some kind that would cause contraction of volume” is perfectly fine. The error lies in the reasoning that follows after:

> Because cosmological constant (which has negative pressure) causes accelerated expansion of the Universe instead of contraction. So negative pressure cannot be thought of as inward pull aiding contraction.

**Gravity that has this negative pressure as a source** is what causes an accelerated expansion.

Another thing is that a pressure (positive or negative) results in a net force (push or pull) only if there is a *pressure gradient* or *pressure difference* like we would have on different sides of a wall in a container filled with gas. Only if there are different pressures inside and outside  would there be the net force acting on its walls. Similarly if our “vacuum” is really a [false vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum) and there exists a “true vacuum” without (or with smaller) dark energy and negative pressure then the negative pressure of our vacuum would exert this pull force on the hypothetical bubble wall separating regions with different vacuums.

Forces exerted by the differences in pressures of vacuum can and had been measured experimentally. This is [the Casimir force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_force) and it could be seen as resulting  from a difference in pressures because the QED vacuum between parallel conducting plates is different from QED vacuum outside those plates.

Another thing that might help with the intuition about negative pressure and its effect on gravitation is the concept of *active mass*: the source of gravity in general relativistic settings is not just the energy density but energy density plus triple the pressure. So the active mass would be  an integral of $(\rho + 3p)$  over the volume.

In static (or nearly static) gravitating systems the analogue of gravitational potential is $\sqrt{g_{00}}$ (in static coordinates and relativistic units), then the relativistic analogue of Poisson equation for gravitational potential is:
$$
  - \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\hat{g}}}\left(\sqrt{-\hat{g}} g^{ij}\left(\sqrt{g_{00}}\right)_{,i}\right)_{,j}\equiv - \nabla ^2 \sqrt{g_{00}}=4 \pi \sqrt{g_{00}}(\rho+3p),
$$
where $g^{ij}$ is the inverse spatial metric, $\hat{g}=\mathrm{det}|\!|g_{ij}|\!|$, comma denotes *partial* derivative, and we assume that the dark energy/cosmological constant  contributes to energy density $\rho$ and pressure $p$ rather than separate its contribution into a separate term.

If a local energy density of nonrelativistic matter (that has $p\approx 0$) dominates over contribution of cosmological constant then we would have ordinary Newtonian equation $\Delta \phi = - 4 \pi \rho$ (with $\phi=\sqrt{g_{00}}-1$). On cosmological scales the pressure term $3p$ with negative pressure of dark energy dominates over $\rho$ producing negative overall active mass. Overall gravitational force (and we can use Newtonian concept of force in this setting) exerted by both matter and dark energy on e.g. a distant galaxy would be directed away from the origin resulting in accelerating cosmological expansion.

For more details, please see this paper aimed at students of general relativity:

- Ehlers, J., Ozsváth, I., & Schucking, E. L. (2006). *Active mass under pressure*. American journal of physics, 74(7), 607-613, [doi:10.1119/1.2198881](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.2198881), [arXiv:gr-qc/0505040](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0505040).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the intuition for positive (negative) pressure is that the system "wants" to expand (contract) into the surrounding space. The cosmological constant only seems like a counterexample because of some conceptual confusions.

OK, so what conceptual confusions am I talking about? It seems that there are two of them:

1. What the system "wants" to do is not necessarily the same as what will actually happen.
2. Expansion INTO the surrounding space is not the same as the expansion OF space itself.

Let's take them one at a time. With regard to the first one, imagine for example a long line of balls connected by rubber bands. Each pair of neighboring balls "wants” to contract, which means the pressure is negative. But whether or not they will actually contract is a completely different matter. If all the rubber bands are equally stretched, then the "desire" of these two balls to contract will be precisely counterbalanced by the force of the surrounding rubber bands pulling them apart.

With regard to number 2, as I said before pressure is the "desire" of the system to expand INTO the surrounding space. General relativity adds a separate effect on top of that, namely that energy, pressure etc. can cause the expansion or contraction OF space itself.

I hope it's clear now that the expansion of the universe due to the cosmological constant does not in any way provide a counterexample to the normal understanding of positive or negative pressure.

Finally, as somewhat of an aside, one could argue that the cosmological constant is not part of the energy momentum tensor of matter and radiation, and therefore does not have negative or positive pressure in the "true" sense.